# CSS Grid Layout Strange Behavior on Window Resize

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

**Chrome Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)** in Windows 7

I'm exploring CSS Grid layout and have come across an odd issue in Chrome (works fine in Firefox). I've created a simple registration form that I want to center horizontally and vertically on the page.

I use three nested grids to structure my layout.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #aaffff;
  height: 100%;
}
#root {
  height: 100%;
}

button,
input,
label {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.formGroup {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

*:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.7);
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

.Input {
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%; */
}
.Input:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.7);
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

.Button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 15px 30px;
}

.Button.primary {
  background: #0000ff;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #000088;
  color: #fff;
}
.Button.primary:hover {
  top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #000088;
}
.Button.primary:active {
  top: 9px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.Button.primary:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

.RegistrationForm-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3% auto 3%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 25% auto 25%;
}
.RegistrationForm-container .copy {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.RegistrationForm-container form {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1% auto 1%;
  grid-template-rows: 25px auto 25px;
}

.RegistrationForm-container form .inner {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1% auto 1%;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
}
.RegistrationForm-container form .inner .emailFormGroup {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.RegistrationForm-container form .inner .buttonFormGroup {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
.App {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div class="RegistrationForm-container">
      <div class="copy">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <p>
          By registering, you agree to our
          <a href="/terms">terms of use and privacy policy</a>.
        </p>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div class="inner">
        
          <div class="formGroup emailFormGroup">
            <input
                   class="Input"
                   type="email"
                   placeholder="Email"
                   autocorrect="false"
                   />
          </div>
          <div class="formGroup buttonFormGroup">
            <button type="submit" class="Button primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While, my grid layout does succeed centering, it misbehaves when the window is resized. When the window is resized larger than the original load size, and then narrowed, a scrollbar appears and the input and button get stuck off to the right.

Only after clicking somewhere in the page or tabbing between the button, input, and terms of use link will it correct itself and snap back into vertical/horizontal centeredness.

Here are demonstrations of the behavior:

https://codepen.io/jdoyle/pen/qXadXJ

https://plnkr.co/edit/rzAAAsfgPVUfxxmXlqYa?p=preview

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue :(. Is there anything else that you do that gives this weird behaviour?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using to test?

Comment: 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I updated the description of how to reproduce the issue. Make sure you widen the window larger than original load size, then narrow the window to see the buggy behavior.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle Does this problem exist in Chrome 59? Because I can't reproduce it. BTW in using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't have Chrome 59 to test with. I'm happy with the solution below, which seems like a better fit than using `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `margin:auto` in a grid does start to act pretty weird.

A way to get the effect you want but avoiding the bug would be to set

```
text-align: center;
```

on the `emailFormGroup` and then remove the `display: block` on email input.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxGyeG

Comment: I'd say report this to the Chrome issue tracker (if it's not already reported) as it surely is a bug.